# Character devices for USB device drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, libusb

I am understanding the USB subsystem. I could see the USB subsystem is registering character devices and major numbers. I have a question, how these character devices and major numbers are linked to the USB drivers or USB device drivers in the Linux Kernel.
Can you guide me to understand where the cdevs registerd by [usb_major_init()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/usb.c#L1019) and [usb_devio_init()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/usb.c#L1025) are linked to the USB device drivers in the Kernel source.

Comment: They are for use by user-space drivers. Kernel-space drivers that call `usb_register` (or `usb_register_driver`) do not use those device numbers.

Comment: Once the USB device driver configures the device then user space applications has to read/write data to the device. 
Example: For USB-to-UART device, the kernel space driver will configure the device, but user space applications has to access the device to read the data.
Can you please provide the driver source path, who is creating device nodes under /dev/bus/usb/ with major numbers 189 or 180.