# Character device interface for USB device drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, libusb

In Kernel USB subsystem is registering chardevices using "[usb_major_init()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/file.c#L120)" and "[usb_devio_init()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/usb.c#L1025)" functions.
How these character device drivers linked to the actual USB drivers registered using "usb_register_driver" and "usb_register_device_driver" functions in the kernel source?

Comment: Is the intention of this question differs from your [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66849274/character-devices-for-usb-device-drivers).

Comment: This question is related to the question I asked for the response [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66849274/character-devices-for-usb-device-drivers). I could have rephrased the question here as the USB drivers registed with "usb_register_driver" and "usb_register_device_driver" will use the registered character devices(usb_major_init and usb_devio_init) fops for user space applications to communicate to the USB drivers.

Comment: There is some linkage within "drivers/usb/core/devio.c". If the USB driver includes an `unlocked_ioctl` handler in its `struct usb_driver`, there is a way to call it using the `USBDEVFS_IOCTL` `ioctl()` request on the character device file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have understood now. I have checked "drivers/usb/core/devio.c" file. The "usbdev_ioctl()", which is registered using "usbdev_file_operations" is calling internally the actual "unlocked_ioctl()" function of usb_driver registered using "usb_register_driver()".
I have taken high level function call names from [kernel source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/devio.c) and pasted [here](https://pastbin.net/untitled-143).

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know (until I looked it up) that USB drivers could have an `unlocked_ioctl` handler. I don't think many USB drivers use it.

Comment: Inside usb_new_device() [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/hub.c#L2531), USB major number details are stored in base device structure of usb_device.After storing, it is calling device_add() to add the device. device_add() is calling device_create_file() [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/base/core.c#L3214). 2nd argument to device_create_file() is neither passed as a argument to device_add() nor created locally in device_add(). My question is where the 2nd argument to device_create_file() is created. Referring v5.12.9 kernel source.

Comment: It seems the 2nd argument "dev_attr_dev" for [device_create_file()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.9/source/drivers/base/core.c#L3214) is defined as static using macro [DEVICE_ATTR_RO(dev)](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.9/source/drivers/base/core.c#L2553)